# Hall of Monuments in Guild Wars

Tags: guild-wars, guild-wars-2

Given the new information on the Hall of Monuments for Guild Wars, what is the easiest and/or best way to earn some statues (and thus Monument Points)?

(edit) More precisely: Which statues are easier to earn? I don't want or need every single statue -- but if there are any that are relatively easy (or easier) to earn, I'd like to get them. (For example, the Hero statue for MOX appears to be very easy.)

For reference: http://hom.guildwars2.com/

Comment: I'm not sure we can really answer this... Firstly, the outlining all the strategies for every single achievement in the HOM is likely potentially [beyond a reasonable scope](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/865/how-large-can-an-objective-questions-scope-get) for us. There are many, many pages dedicated to this on the official GW wiki. Secondly, "easiest/best" can be rather subjective, especially considering the varied work needed for stuff like the Valor weapons. I wouldn't really characterize any of the titles as "easy," mostly "time consuming."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi you should check out Massively's series [The Road to 50](http://www.massively.com/tag/the-road-to-50/) which goes into some depth and highlighting the easiest/more difficult statues to unlock. For me the easiest ones have been armour and minipets. The Skill hunter titles are loadsa fun and easy to get (4 titles with the Legendary one too). Sunspear points title is fairly easy, each of the Hero/Guardian ones are pretty easy to get too.
Prices of a lot of materials have really shot up as a result of the HoM link, so beware. Don't buy now if you don't have to.

Please, remember to have fun. Nothing is worth boring yourself for. Grinding for titles/achievements is pointless if it's not fun.

Comment: There is now an official blog post on this topic also.
http://www.arena.net/blog/john-stummes-guide-to-the-hall-of-monuments

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy(or legit) way of earning the monuments as they all take quite a bit of money and time.  However, there are many available ways of earning those titles if you have a large amount of stashed platinum handy.

There are many services being offered on community sites like guildwarsguru where people are willing to perform tasks like vanquishing certain areas for you or do the hard mode missions, for a fee.

And of course, having enough money will buy you the 3 consumable titles fairly quickly, as well as the zkey and the lucky/unlucky monuments.

And both the official and unofficial wikis have a lot of help in terms of strategies to do for title grinding.

Finally, as a word of warning, using a program to drink alcohol while you are afk to rack up 10k minutes is against the TOS and your account may be banned for botting. (Happened to one of my guildies)

Comment: There's an achievement for being drunk a lot in-game?  That's... wrong.

Comment: Indeed there is, and it takes a *long* time to get.

Comment: @bwarner, not only that, there are skills that improve while you are drunk :)

Comment: Just like real life.